# Auto Layout Collection view according to various screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a collection view inside a normal view controller using the collection view delegate and data source. I'm using the sizeForItemAtIndexPath but it doesn't resize the cell.

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: screenSize.width / 3, height: screenSize.width / 3)
}
```

The collection view is assigned the constraints using autoLayout properly.

**How it looks in iPhone5**
[image]

**How it should look**
[image]

I know the estimatedItemSize is used but I'm unable to use it since this is not a UICollectionViewController. Thanks for any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

- Confirming to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.
- collectionView's width = screen's width.
- Min Spacing for cells is zero. You can change it from the Interface Builder (Select the collectionView -> show size inspector -> set min spacing to 0), or by implementing `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` returning zero.

I hope that answered your question.