# UICollectionView Full Width

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm currently scaffolding an app with a UiCollectionView (one cell containing a UITableView). I'm trying to make it full width but there is a large margin on the right when I run through the emulator:

[image]

I've used the autoresizing tool in the size inspector to autoresize on the right but now could do with some advice here on how to make the UiCollectionView have the same margin on the right as it does on the left?

Alignment settings of the Collection view:

[image]

Comment: did you test it on a real device?

Comment: you have a collectionview which contains only one cell which is  atableview ? if yes then why not use tableView directly ?

Comment: Because I'm writing an app that is a collection of vertical lists. You swipe right to see the next vertical list - a bit like the default calendar app. The mechanics of this are fine - all works well. The issue is the margin as shown above.

Comment: Tripple check (and maybe show) your constraints.

Comment: @Mattl please show us your constraints..

Comment: please show us how do you set the constraints.

Comment: it should be a problem with the constraints, show it or maybe upload the project.

Comment: @shallowThought I've not got any constraints so far. Just the alignment settings as shown above.

Comment: I think that [this is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944207/auto-layout-collection-view-according-to-various-screen-sizes/39944449#39944449) of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: `x` + `y` are > 0, width is probably wrong also.

Comment: @Ahmad F Yes the CollectionView width does not equal the screen width. That's what i'm trying to correct.

Comment: What about using AutoLayout?